# Signs for marginal effects and regression coefficients are inconsistent for beta regression

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, marginal-effect

I have conducted a zero-one inflated beta (ZOIB) regression using a logit link function for explaining tenure incidence in colleges and universities.  Tenure incidence is a proportion in the interval [0,1].  I have 12 explanatory variables in my model.  This is the part of the STATA report for the regression corresponding to the interval (0,1):
[image]

I requested the marginal effects at the means, which are reported here in the dy/dx column:
[image]
I expected the signs on the marginal effects to be the same as the signs on the corresponding regression coefficients, but the signs for TUITION, PUBLSERV2, LABRMKT, PROFDEGS, and MEDICAL1 are not the same.  I based my expectation that the signs would be the same on this equation, which is the definition of a marginal effect in a logistic regression:

[image]

where bk is the regression coefficient for the k-th independent variable Xk and P is the probability.  Because both P and (1 - P) must be positive, the regression coefficient determines the sign of the partial derivative.

This is the code that was used to run the ZOIB regression and call for the marginals:

[image]

My question is:  Why don't five of my marginals have the same signs as their respective regression coefficients?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated!  Could you please focus your question?  Perhaps share your regression equation?  Or state your question in mathematical terms?  Also, clearly stating your question and separating it out of the main body paragraph will help reviewers answer.

Comment: A ZOIB model can have three coefficients for each predictor; which coefficients are you talking about? Did you include the predictor in all three parts, or just the beta regression part?

Comment: I am talking about the coefficients labeled "proportion" in STATA, i.e., the coefficients corresponding to the range of the predicted variable (tenure incidence) between zero and one (and not including zero and one)--that is (0,1).

Comment: I have edited my original question in response to the comment by R. Carnell.

Comment: Can you also include the code you used to fit the model? That's the only way we can resolve ambiguities about which model you fit. You didn't answer my question about whether you included the predictor in all three parts or just the beta part.

Comment: Noah, I'm sorry.  I guess I didn't fully understand your question about including the predictor in all three parts.  I am working long-distance with my colleague and don't have access to the code.  I will contact him for it and then share it.  Thanks.

Comment: I just received the STATA code my colleague used to runt he ZOIB regression and call for the marginals.  I have posted it in my original question.